# What is replacement of SSL/HTTPS in drupal to encrypt login credentials

Tags: users

I have one question, in my website i am not using ssl so my drupal login send id and password as plain text, then i have used the **encrypt_sumissions** module but that is use **jcryption** library but this is not useful, I want to know how can i encrypt login credentials without ssl/https.

Should I change in drupal core, I am new to this please provide me detailed information.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Save yourself the headache and use TLS/SSL. Drupal won't, and isn't meant to, solve your problem. It isn't worth trying to cobble something together. If the cost of the certificate is an issue, go to https://letsencrypt.org/ and get a free cert.